# Kibana Canvas error: Invalid string. Length must be a multiple of 4

Tags: canvas, kibana, elk

I am using version 7.16.2 of Kibana. I am adding a dropdown filter in Canvas.

[image]

Let's say the index pattern is `*-*_stage`. This index pattern includes 100 data streams. When trying to add this index pattern in the Canvas dropdown filter, I am getting this error:

[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to enlarge proxy-buffer of nginx by adding the following Ingress Annotations for the Kibana Nginx Ingress:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 16k
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-max-temp-file-size: 1024m
```